# enet in R doesn't work because of Error saying "Some of the columns of x have zero variance"

Tags: r, kaggle, enet

I'm starting out to predict the beginner kaggle competition called "
House Prices: Advanced Regression Techniques". My linear regression worked fine. Until Ridge regression gave this error.

`Error in enet(x = as.matrix(trainPredictors), y = trainClasses, lambda = 1e-04) : 
  Some of the columns of x have zero variance`

my prefer cleansed data is called complete_data5.Rdata. and the code can be found in model_ridge.r. File can be found here: https://github.com/kennethng2017/HousingPrice

`ridgeModel <- enet(x = as.matrix(trainPredictors), y = trainClasses,
                   lambda = 0.0001)
Error in enet(x = as.matrix(trainPredictors), y = trainClasses, lambda = 1e-04) : 
  Some of the columns of x have zero variance`

The trainPredictors has dummy variable.

**SessionInfo**

```
 sessionInfo()
 R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
 Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
 Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.4

 locale:
 [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

 attached base packages:
 [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

 other attached packages:
 [1] reshape2_1.4.2  corrplot_0.77   dplyr_0.5.0     elasticnet_1.1 
 [5] lars_1.2        Metrics_0.1.2   doSNOW_1.0.14   snow_0.4-2     
 [9] iterators_1.0.8 foreach_1.4.3   caret_6.0-73    ggplot2_2.2.1  
 [13] lattice_0.20-34

 loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.10       compiler_3.3.3     nloptr_1.0.4           plyr_1.8.4        
 [5] tools_3.3.3        lme4_1.1-12        tibble_1.3.0       nlme_3.1-131      
 [9] gtable_0.2.0       mgcv_1.8-17        Matrix_1.2-8           DBI_0.6-1         
 [13] parallel_3.3.3     SparseM_1.76       stringr_1.2.0           MatrixModels_0.4-1
 [17] stats4_3.3.3       grid_3.3.3         nnet_7.3-12        R6_2.2.0          
 [21] minqa_1.2.4        car_2.1-4          magrittr_1.5       scales_0.4.1      
 [25] codetools_0.2-15   ModelMetrics_1.1.0 MASS_7.3-45        splines_3.3.3     
 [29] assertthat_0.2.0   pbkrtest_0.4-7     colorspace_1.3-2     labeling_0.3      
 [33] quantreg_5.29      stringi_1.1.5      lazyeval_0.2.0     munsell_0.4.3
```

Please free feel to ask any questions.

Comment: I downloaded `complete_data5.Rdata` and used Hometrain data: `ridgeModel <- enet(x = as.matrix(HometrainX), y = HometrainY, lambda = 0.0001)`. No error messages. You should clarify what `trainPredictors` and `trainClasses` are.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to upload the mode_ridge.r file into my GitHub. I just did it. The `trainPredicters` and `trainClasses` are a random subset(80%) of HometrainX and HometrainY. I wanted to test the result of the regression with the other 20%.

Comment: In your datasets there are some 0/1 variables with very few 1s. When you randomly split the dataset in training and testing sets, it is likely that some of these variables have only 0s in the training set, i.e. some of *the columns of x have zero variance*

Comment: Thank you. That makes a lot of sense. Maybe I'll try another method. Lasso regression or gradient boosting?

Comment: No. Your problem is due to variables with zero variance. Changing method does not solve the problem. I suggest to delete variables with a low number of 1s.

Comment: It works fine with linear regression. I can use nearzerovar() to remove the dummy variable.

Comment: Why is this tagged with `caret`?